# if conditional based on output in batch?

Tags: redirect, if-statement, batch-file, for-loop

I'd like to redirect my program to a certain set of commands if the cmd window outputs: "Can't find ref_eng...", how can i accomplish this? In the codes below, at the 2nd line containing the For, is the location where the cmd.exe can output "can't find ref_eng" if !refLogPath! doesnt exist. At this point, I'd like to redirect my program elsewhere...

```
<!logPath! (
For /F "tokens=*" %%R in (!refLogPath!) DO (
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        ECHO Check certain lines of code
            )
    set logLine=
        set /p logLine=
    set refLogLine=%%R
    REM Check line by line of log against refLog
    REM assume ALL times have been replaced with: "xx:xx:xx"

    REM if corresponding lines mismatch
    if NOT "!logLine!"=="!refLogLine!" (
        Echo.
        Echo line below is Incorrect:
        set lnCorrect=false
        REM output to command line: can be put into .log/.txt later
        REM output ANY and ALL incorrect line in log file
            ECHO !logLine!
                           )
                       )    
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check refLogPath before the for loop.

Eg:

```
   if !refLogPath!xx == xx (
     REM refLogPath is empty or unset
     goto :SomewhereElse
   ) else (
     if not exist !refLogPath! (
       REM refLogPath is missing
       goto :SomewhereElse
     )
   )
   For /F "tokens=*" %%R in (!refLogPath!) DO (
      ...etc...
```